# Failure to find table in SQLite database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

So I'm trying to use SQLalchemy to export the data from an SQLite database to a Mysql database using the following script. Assume the database connection works fine and I haven't made any typos with the names of the tables. The database file is in the same directory as the script

After running the script I get given the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: table1

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Float, VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


#Later on this can have a foreign_key constraint so that we can relate people and places
class locale(Base):
    __tablename__='table1'
    ogc_fid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    location = Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=True)
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)
    entries = Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)

class personae(Base):
    __tablename__='table2'
    name = Column(VARCHAR(255), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    details = Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=True)
    entries = Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=True)

sqlite_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///Database.sqlite', pool_pre_ping=True)

mysql_engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306/maindb')

SQLite_session = sessionmaker(bind=sqlite_engine)
sqlite_session = SQLite_session()


MySQLsession = sessionmaker(bind=mysql_engine)
mysql_session = MySQLsession()

Base.metadata.create_all(mysql_engine)

mysql_session.commit()
sqlite_session.close()
mysql_session.close()
```

table1 definitely exists in the database file. SQLite should not have any access permissions apart from those of the underlying operating system, so I'm at a loss as to why my script can't seem to access the database file.

https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8 is linked by the error message, and indicates that it is probably an issue with the database software, but I can't work out what the problem might be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have posted my script above:

Comment: You said the sqlite database is in the same directory as the script, but that's not where it's going to look.  It's going to look in the "current directory" for the process.  For example, if you do `python xx/yy/zz.py`, the current directory is the one that contains `xx`, not the one that contains `zz.py`.

Comment: Update: At your suggestion I've tried using the absolute filepath. The error has now changed to 'Unknown column 'table1.ogc_fid' in 'field list''